# How to keep Firebase in sync with mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We need to keep our Firebase data in sync with other databases.
if i hav updated data in mysql db it should be refected in firebase

This needs to be as close to real-time as possible, we can't just export a nightly dump of the Firebase JSON or anything like that, aside from the fact that this will get rather large.

Answer (score 4):

I keep my Firebase data "synced" with an ElasticSearch instance.
To do this I have a NodeJS app that listens for changes in Firebase and creates/updates my indexes in ElasticSearch.

It works very well for me, you can probably do the same. A Node server that listens for changes, gets the JSON and puts the appropriate value in MySQL.

I'll be happy to receive any comment on this solution.

Hope it helps ;)